# Install R packages in archive

Tags: r, package, installation

How can I install packages that are in archive, in Windows ?

http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/

When I try to install the tar.gz downloaded from the archive I get the following error:

> ```
> Error in gzfile(file, "r") : cannot open the connection
> In addition: Warning messages:
> 1: In unzip(zipname, exdir = dest) : error 1 in extracting from zip file
> 2: In gzfile(file, "r") :
>   cannot open compressed file 'grasp_2.5-7.tar.gz/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
> ```

Comment: You may need Rtools for windows source installations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try the function `install_version` in `devtools`. Let us suppose you want to install version 0.8 of `ggplot2`, you can call it as `install_version('ggplot2', '0.8')`. If you are on Windows, you can follow the instructions [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#The-Windows-toolset) to build packages from source.

Answer (score 5):

You can download the sources (tar.gz files) and install them using:

```
R CMD INSTALL packagename.tar.gz
```

Comment: I tried with install from local zip and I get an error (see question)

Comment: If it is the same error , then you should say so. At the moment we do not know what you are seeing and there are several possible errors, even if you have a local copy of the gzipped file.

Comment: yes, it is the same error, comment and edit of the question was made at the same time. the szipped file was downloaded from http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/. I already tried the 3 versions available and I get the same error. I will try with Rtools

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem installing graph package from archive. The package is required for another package (bnclasify).

```
chooseBioCmirror() #select a different mirror than CRAN. This mirror may be #because is the one that has bnclasify in it (check this statement)

setRepositories() #In here you can select as many as you want to search for the       #package you need

ap <- available.packages() #list of all available packages

"graph" %in% rownames(ap) #search the package you need by name (return TRUE or #FALSE). 

install.packages("graph", dependencies=TRUE) #if the last statement TRUE then #install the package like normally
```