# need archived version of r DMwR 0.2.3.zip for windows binary

Tags: r

need archived version of r DMwR 0.2.3.zip for windows binary
current version is DMwR 0.3.0
I need the old version ,thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [R packages in archive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161534/r-packages-in-archive)

Answer (score 1):

Build it yourself.

Download the appropriate `.tar.gz` file and build from source

The following

```
install.packages("~/Downloads/DMwR_0.2.3.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

worked for me!

With the obvious caveat that archived versions are archived for a reason.