# Birch package replacement in latest R version

Tags: r, algorithm, cluster-analysis

study birch algorithm in R, try to install old version birch package in latest R
version(3.4.1). But it doesn't work.

Any solution about this case? Is there an replacement about birch package for birch algorithm or any better way to make old birch package working in latest R (3.4.1 version) ?

---

**Edit:** I have [seen this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194409/how-do-i-install-a-package-that-has-been-archived-from-cran), and tried to install the old package of archived birch on Windows by RTools. Installation process got no issue. But when use this package in R always meet fatal error ( aborted R session).

So, just wonder if some new package already replace this old birch package to realize birch algorithm?

Comment: I think it never was a usable, complete implementation of BIRCH. In fact, I yet have to see a good implementation that fully implements birch, and not just the cf tree.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse, I am just studying  to learn birch algorithm and use it in R. Even it never was a usable,complete implementation of birch,could you help to introduce the better way( some good replacement package or some code can realize this algorithm in R)? Thanks!

Comment: As said, I do *not* know of any usable, complete implementation of BIRCH. The CF-tree is a nice idea, but the clusters you get from the leaves are shoot. There are too many details missing in the paper on how to get a better clustering. Plus, the low-level memory management etc. necessary for BIRCH are a pain.