# Installing BayesLogit package

Tags: r, package, cran

I am trying to install the BayesLogit package in R.  The package was removed from the CRAN website, but I have the source files BayesLogit_0.6.tar.gz.  I try running

```
install.packages("BayesLogit_0.6.tar.gz", type = "source", repos = NULL)
```

but get the following error: installation of package ‘BayesLogit_0.6.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status.

Can anyone help, or can you no longer install this package?  I have the package installed on another machine, which I installed it back when it was on the CRAN website.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install the package on my Ubuntu machine with `devtools::install_version("BayesLogit", "0.6")`

Because the package has C++ source files, you well need compilation tools. If you use Windows, that means you will need to install RTools. On Mac, you will need the Xcode [command line tools](https://developer.apple.com/downloads). See also [How do I install a package that has been archived from CRAN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194409/how-do-i-install-a-package-that-has-been-archived-from-cran) and https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

Comment: I am trying to install on a mac.  Running your command above gives the error:  installation of package ‘/var/folders/0m/wz75_3gs17z6pd48q6v4g41w0000gn/T//Rtmp0VfIu3/remotes3843f86f7ef/BayesLogit’ had non-zero exit status.

Comment: Perhaps I need to install Xcode... I will give that a try.

Comment: Yes, you do need to install Xcode. I will update the answer.

Comment: Okay I have installed xcode, and when trying to rerun your command, I get ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘BayesLogit’.  Is there something I need to do within xcode after installing it, or is it sufficient to install xcode and run your command within R?

Comment: @norm850 do you have `gfortran` installed? If not, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Linux

Run these commands in the R session:

```r
install.packages("devtools")  # optional, in case you don't have it
require(devtools)
install_version("BayesLogit", version = "0.6")  # the latest version on CRAN archive
```

## macOS

Compiling BayesLogit from source requires GFortran, which requires XCode and command-line tools:

- install XCode from the App Store, or install only command-line tools only (e.g., from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-install-command-line-tools))
- install  `gfortran`,  e.g. using [an appropriate disk image](https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS/releases)
- run the same code as above inside R:

```r
install.packages("devtools")  # optional, in case you don't have it
require(devtools)
install_version("BayesLogit", version = "0.6")  # the latest version on CRAN archive
```

## Alternative package

The [GitHub page of `BayesLogit`](https://github.com/jwindle/BayesLogit/) was last updated 11 months ago, so I venture a guess that it will not be on CRAN. An alternative is [this package](https://github.com/kasparmartens/PolyaGamma), which implements the same Polya-Gamma scheme as `BayesLogit` and has very similar syntax:

```r
# BayesLogit
obj <- BayesLogit::logit(y=y, X=X, P0=diag(rep(precision, ncol(X)), samp=n_samples, burn=burn)
# PolyaGamma
obj <- PolyaGamma::gibbs_sampler(y=y, X=X, lambda=precision, n_iter_total=burn + n_samples, burn_in=burn)
```

To install the `PolyaGamma` package, run these commands in your R session:

```r
install.packages("devtools")  # optional, in case you don't have it
require(devtools)
devtools::install_github("kasparmartens/PolyaGamma")
library(PolyaGamma)
```