# Download older version of a package that has been removed from CRAN

Tags: r, text-mining, archive, cran

I resume working on text mining after a substantial period of hiatus, but soon found out that the package `RTextTools` has been removed from CRAN and was no longer in maintenance. I tried to download it manually from CRAN archive using

```
url <- "http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RTextTools/RTextTools_1.4.2.tar.gz"
install.packages(url, repos=NULL, type="source")
```

but my `R` shows

> there is no package called 'RTextTools'.

I then tried out the trick recommended by this earlier [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194409/how-do-i-install-a-package-that-has-been-archived-from-cran) by using

```
url <- "http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RTextTools/RTextTools_1.4.2.tar.gz"
pkgFile <- "RTextTools_1.4.2.tar.gz"
download.file(url = url, destfile = pkgFile)
install.packages(c('randomForest', 'tree', 'ipred', 'maxent', 'glmnet', 'tau'))
install.packages(pkgs=pkgFile, type="source", repos=NULL)
```

But this didn't work either.
The `RTextTools` package has many handy features I appreciate and I really do want to maintain an older version of it in my folder, is there any other ways I can install the archived version of this package on my `R`?

Comment: `https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RTextTools/`. To install download zip files and install by providing path to `install.packages()`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is located at the `tree` dependency package installation:

```
install.packages("tree")
```

Throws an error (my R version is 3.5.0):

> ERROR: This is R version 3.5.0,  'tree' package requires R >= 3.6.0
>
> In R CMD INSTALL
>
> Warning in install.packages :
>   installation of package
>         ‘tree_1.0-40.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

To solve it update R to version >= 3.6.0.

Comment: or downgrade to an older value of `tree`.  Look into using the [snapshot package](https://mran.microsoft.com/documents/rro/reproducibility).