# Rattle: ‘RGtk2Extras’ not available

Tags: r, windows-10, rattle, rgtk2

I am trying to get Rattle set up on my computer for a master's course I'm taking.

I am running Windows 10 and have R version *3.6*, RStudio version *1.2.1335*, and Rattle version *5.2* installed.

Using the following code I tried to install Rattle with all the suggested packages:

```
install.packages("rattle", dep=c("Suggests"))
```

There are two packages that are currently unavailable: playwith, RGtk2Extras.

Are there any workarounds?

Update 1: I tried installing the archived version of RGtk2Extras and I am receiving this error message

> Warning: Failed to load RGtk2 dynamic library, attempting to install it.
>   Please install GTK+ from http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/gtk+/2.22/gtk+-bundle_2.22.1-20101227_win32.zip
>   If the package still does not load, please ensure that GTK+ is installed and that it is on your PATH environment variable
>   IN ANY CASE, RESTART R BEFORE TRYING TO LOAD THE PACKAGE AGAIN

I have RGtk2 version 2.20.36 installed and it appears to load fine when I type library(Rgtk2)
I also know that I have GTK+ installed because Rattle asked me to install it and I did.

Thank you!

Comment: try install.packages("rattle", dependencies = TRUE), or manually install each package it says is not available

Comment: Those packages were removed from CRAN. You can [install archived versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194409/how-do-i-install-a-package-that-has-been-archived-from-cran) of the packages as a work around, but they might not work with the latest version of R. The future of rattle doesn't look good unless the author updates to use different dependencies. There's not much you can do about that.

Comment: Thanks - I tried installing the archived version of the RGtk2Extras package but now I'm getting this error message: Warning: Failed to load RGtk2 dynamic library, attempting to install it.
Please install GTK+ from http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/gtk+/2.22/gtk+-bundle_2.22.1-20101227_win32.zip
If the package still does not load, please ensure that GTK+ is installed and that it is on your PATH environment variable
IN ANY CASE, RESTART R BEFORE TRYING TO LOAD THE PACKAGE AGAIN

Comment: Can you start up Rattle? It probably works mostly without them (they are suggested, not required). Those two packages need to be removed from the Rattle dependencies.  You may like to install from togaware  install.packages("rattle", repos="https://rattle.togaware.com", type="source")

Comment: @GrahamWilliams Yes I can start it up, so I guess I can just keep working through my class material.  When I try to install from togaware I'm informed that package 'rattle' is not available (for R version 3.6.0).  Thanks for the fast response.

Comment: For completeness, please note that the dependencies on RGtk2Extras and playwith were removed from Rattle version 5.2.8. Installation works just fine on R 3.6.1 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS: install.packages("rattle", repos="rattle.togaware.com", type="source")