# Cannot Install RADammi package

Tags: r

I am trying to install the RADammi package on R 3.6 using "devtools", however I receive this error:

> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/taham/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>
> ERROR: dependencies 'Biostrings', 'IRanges' are not available for package 'RADami'
>   * removing 'C:/Users/taham/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/RADami'
>
> Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from URL:
>   (converted from warning) installation of package  > ‘C:/Users/taham/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpycMnQ2/remotes11246cb38f0/RADami’ had non-zero exit status.

It is an old package that has been removed from CRAN
https://rdrr.io/cran/RADami/

how should I install it?

update:
I finally could manage to install the two dependencies using below command:

> if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
>
> install.packages("BiocManager")
>
> BiocManager::install("Biostrings")
>
> BiocManager::install("IRanges")

I have downloaded the zip archived RADami file and tried to install the package, I receive this fetal error again:

> install.packages("C:/Users/taham/Downloads/RADami_1.1-2.tar.gz", repos = NULL,  type = "source")
>
> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/taham/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>
> - installing *source* package 'RADami' ...
>
> ** package 'RADami' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>
> ** using staged installation
>
> ** R
>
> ** data
>
> ** inst
>
> ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
>
> Error: objects 'c.phylo', 'c.multiPhylo' are not exported by 'namespace:ape'
>   Execution halted
>
> ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'RADami'
>
> - removing 'C:/Users/taham/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/RADami'
>
> Warning in install.packages :
>
> installation of package ‘C:/Users/taham/Downloads/RADami_1.1-2.tar.gz’ had non-> zero exit status

I get the same error when using devtools

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install a package that has been archived from CRAN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194409/how-do-i-install-a-package-that-has-been-archived-from-cran)

Comment: not really, I have already downloaded the latest archived zip file, but now my problem is in installing the dependencies, being 'BioString', before manually installing the actual package

Comment: Do you have package ‘ape’ installed?

Comment: I think I do; 
> library(ape)

Attaching package: ‘ape’

The following object is masked from ‘package:Biostrings’:

    complement

The following objects are masked from ‘package:hierfstat’:

    pcoa, varcomp

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to first install "IRanges" and "Biostrings" from BioConductor:

```
library(devtools)
install_bioc("IRanges")
install_bioc("Biostrings")
```

Though these have other dependencies such as "S4Vector" which you may need to install manually also.

Then you should be able to install RADami:

```r
install_url("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RADami/RADami_1.0-3.tar.gz")
```

Comment: I could manage somehow to install 'IRanges' but for 'Biostrings', it doesn't work. I tried both : install_bioc("BioStrings") and if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
  install.packages("BiocManager")

Comment: @Masse what error does install_bioc("BioStrings") give you?

Comment: Downloading Bioconductor repo https://git.bioconductor.org/packages/BioStrings
Error in git2r::clone(url, bundle, credentials = x$credentials, progress = FALSE) : 
  Error in 'git2r_clone': remote error: FATAL: R any packages/BioStrings nobody DENIED by fallthru
(or you mis-spelled the reponame)

Comment: @Masse I think it should be `install_bioc("Biostrings")` (without the capital) - my bad.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue with installing from the CRAN archive, but was successfully able to install it from the developer's Github. In R:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("andrew-hipp/RADami")
```