# data set ‘NYTimes’ not found

Tags: r, topic-modeling

I'm working with `topicmodels` package:

```
library(topicmodels)
library(tm)
```

I tried to load the `NYTimes` dataset. But:

```
data(NYTimes)
```

returns the error:

```
Warning message:
In data(NYTimes) : data set ‘NYTimes’ not found
```

I took this code from a textbook on `R`.

Comment: That data set does not exist in any of the libraries you mention. Maybe go back at the textbook and find the source

Comment: The package containing that dataset is `RTextTools` which has been archived on CRAN. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194409/how-do-i-install-a-package-that-has-been-archived-from-cran) for how to install an archived package.

Comment: That dataset is described as "a sample dataset containing labeled headlines from The New York Times" in both package [RTextTools](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RTextTools/index.html) and package [maxent](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/maxent/index.html). Both packages were removed from the CRAN repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a Google search with the terms`"CRAN" data(NYTimes)`, you should quickly find that the "RTextTools" package has a dataset by that name.

A bit of further searching yields this information at CRAN:

```
Package ‘RTextTools’ was removed from the CRAN repository.

Formerly available versions can be obtained from the archive.

Archived on 2019-03-05 as depends on archived package 'maxent' by the same non-maintainer.
```

So go to the [Package Archive for RTextTools](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RTextTools), download it, check to see if it needs to be compiled (it doesn't), and install with the argument `repo` set to NULL. See `?install.packages` for further details. That turns out not to work since attempts to install pkg:maxent fail at the compiling process.

The other option would be to download, unzip, navigate to the ../data/ directory inside the expanded package directory and then also unzip the compacted file by that name (with a .csv extension).

Edwards suggestion is also feasible in which case you can go directly to https://github.com/cran/RTextTools/blob/master/data/NYTimes.csv.gz and download and unzip the file without the need to install the package.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you meant "... tried to **download** ...". (not upload). And that's not an error, it's a warning. Anyway, ...

You need to load the **package** that contains that particular **dataset**, `NYTimes`.

A quick search of the CRAN website says the data is in the `RTextTools` package, which has unfortunately been archived. Try the GitHub website: https://github.com/cran/RTextTools/

Comment: Hah, I didn't realize that a minor edit would unlock my voting rights, but it does.