# package ‘gputools’ is not available for this version of R

Tags: r, gpu, cran

I can't install the library "gputools" in rstudio (https://rdrr.io/cran/gputools/).

```html
install.packages("gputools")
```

> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/david/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.1’
> (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
> Warning in install.packages :
> package ‘gputools’ is not available for this version of R
>
> A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
> see the ideas at
> https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

OS: Windows 10 pro
R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)

It seemse the issue is the package was removed from cran so I can't download it through normal means: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gputools/index.html

How can I get the library installed and will it work? I need it in order to do fast matrix multiplication.
Thankyou for your help!

Comment: I tried solving the issue using the solution found here(How should I deal with "package 'xxx' is not available (for R version x.y.z)" warning?) but it didn't work                                                                        > library(remotes)
> install_version("gputools", 1.1)
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'gputools'
I also tried the other methods but the space limit for comments is not much, but the point is none worked for me.

Comment: [According to CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/package=gputools) that package was removed from the server on 2017-12-19 because the authors did not make necessary updates to run on newer versions of R. There's a [guide on installing from archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194409/how-do-i-install-a-package-that-has-been-archived-from-cran) but most likely you'll also need a very old version of R to actually run that package.