# Is there a function to calculate the scatter matrix in R language?

Tags: r, feature-selection, unsupervised-learning, scatter-matrix

Recently I have been trying to use an optimizer to make feature selections for clustering. I need a fitness function to tell the optimizer which feature set is better. So I refer to the criteria mentioned in the book *"Introduction to Statistical Pattern Recognition 2nd Ed chapter 10,10.2- Keinosuke Fukunaga"*. The content is shown below.[image: Scatter Matrices and Separability Criteria]
[image: Scatter Matrices and Separability Criteria2]

I have found a function(ScatterMatrices()) in Matlab to calculate the value J. As shown below.[image: ppt4]
However, I didn't find any function similar to ScatterMatrices() in Matlab. I would appreciate it if you could help me.

Answer (score 0):

[withinSS: Within-class Sum of Squares Matrix](https://rdrr.io/cran/DiscriMiner/man/withinSS.html)

"Calculates within-class sum of squares and cross product matrix (a.k.a. within-class scatter matrix)"

Which is available in the archive [Index of /src/contrib/Archive/DiscriMiner](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/DiscriMiner/)

[How do I install a package that has been archived from CRAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194409/how-do-i-install-a-package-that-has-been-archived-from-cran)