# Problem with installing the augsynth package in R

Tags: r, r-package

I'm trying to install the [augemented syntheric control](https://github.com/ebenmichael/augsynth) package in R, but it seems that it needs 2 other packages that have been archived. ("Synth" and "LowRankQP")

Even when I install them from the [archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194409/how-do-i-install-a-package-that-has-been-archived-from-cran), I ran to the same problem.

I installed the "Synth" and "LowRankQP" succesfuly, based on @r2evans suggestion

```
remotes::install_github(cran/LowRankQP)
remotes::install_github(cran/Synth)
```

and Here is the code that I use to install the package.

```
install.packages("devtools")install.packages("devtools")

devtools::install_github("ebenmichael/augsynth")
```

And here is new  the error:

```
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :  
  namespace 'rlang' 1.0.6 is being loaded, but >= 1.1.0 is required 
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImport -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace 
Execution halted 
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'augsynth'
```

Any Ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: If a package has been archived, there are some options for installing them: (1) go to the archive directory for each package (e.g., https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/LowRankQP/), download the version you want, and install it as a local file; (2) use `remotes::install_github("cran/LowRankQP")`.

Comment: If you have done that for `"Synth"` and `"LowRankQP"`, and then again try to install the `augsynth` package from its github repo, and that still fails, then the problem may not be simply the archived status. In that case, please [edit] your question and add (into a [code block]) the code you used to install each (I'm looking for warnings/errors).

Comment: Thanks @r2evans . Yes I exatly said that in the question I posted. "Even when I install them from archive...." The code to install is exactly the one from the github page of the package. I will edit the question.

Comment: You haven't shown what I suggested. (1) Download [LowRankQP](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/LowRankQP/LowRankQP_1.0.5.tar.gz) and [Synth](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/Synth/Synth_1.1-6.tar.gz). (2) `install.packages("path/to/Synth_1.1-6.tar.gz")` (and same for the other). (3) Only when both of those succeed can you try `remotes::install_github("ebenmichael/augsynth")`.

Comment: Thnaks a lot @r2evans . will update ir now.
 remotes::install_github worked for LowRankQP and synth. But still a new problem with augsynth.