# Trying to download 'USAboundaries' from R Archive

Tags: r, install.packages

I am trying to download the 'USAboundaries' package from the R Archive and am receiving this error:

```
install.packages(pkgs=pkgFile, type="source", repos=NULL)

Error in getOctD(x, offset, len) : invalid octal digit
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘USAboundaries_0.4.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

There were no dependencies listed in the 'USAboundaries_0.4.0.tar.gz' description.

This is what I have so far:

```
url <- "https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/USAboundaries/index.html"
pkgFile <- "USAboundaries_0.4.0.tar.gz"
download.file(url = url, destfile = pkgFile)
install.packages(pkgs=pkgFile, type="source", repos=NULL)
```

Comment: Are you on a windows machine? Try `download.file(url = url, destfile = pkgFile, mode="wb")`

Comment: The simplest way to install the latest version is probably `remotes::install_version("USAboundaries", "0.4.0")`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
pkgFile <- "USAboundaries_0.4.0.tar.gz"

url <- paste0("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/USAboundaries/", pkgFile)
download.file(url = url, destfile = pkgFile)
install.packages(pkgs = pkgFile, type = "source", repos = NULL)
```

see also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194409/how-do-i-install-a-package-that-has-been-archived-from-cran)