# Is there an alternative package available for geoRglm (for R version 4.2.2)?

Tags: r, spatial

When I try to install geoRglm using `install.packages('geoRglm')`, I receive this error: `"Warning in install.packages : package ‘geoRglm’ is not available for this version of R"`

Is there an updated version or alternative package I could use to create a spatial model?

Thank you!

Comment: This package was archived in 2020. You can try `remotes::install_version("geoRglm", version = "0.9-16")` to get the most recent version that existed before it was removed from CRAN

Comment: If you view the CRAN page, you can see the [package was archived in 2020](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=geoRglm) so there's no version available for any version of R. You could [install from archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194409/how-do-i-install-a-package-that-has-been-archived-from-cran) but that package might have unfixed flaws. Asking for replacement packages is considered off-topic. It's better if describe a specific problem you are trying to solve and, if necessary, other packages may be included in the answer.

Comment: At the author's [page for the package](https://genetics.ghpc.au.dk/ofch/geoRglm.html) (the URL has changed a bit, confusingly), he says the package is available on request.