# Which R version to be able to use colbycol package

Tags: r, csv, import

I would like to use the colbycol package in order to read specific columns from a big csv file into R. I'm on a windows system using R studio.
However I cannot import the package and get the following message:

```
> install.packages("colbycol", dependencies = TRUE)
Installing package into ‘\\GBW9061117.gothenburg.vcc.ford.com/JHERMAN8$/DATA/R/win-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘colbycol’ is not available (for R version 3.1.1)
```

Does anybody know how I can find out which version of R to use in order to use the colbycol package?

Comment: Your package has been archived.  You can tell this really easily by simply going here: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/colbycol/index.html

Comment: What does that mean? Not usable?

Comment: A quick search on SO for `[r] package archived` will lead you to http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+package+archived where you will find answers.  For example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161534/r-packages-in-archive or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15973594/how-to-build-an-archived-package-on-r-3-0-0 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091304/efficiently-getting-older-versions-of-r-packages

Comment: Not an answer to your question (but perhaps one to your problem): try the [LaF package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/LaF/index.html) instead